# How to construct an automata that contains an $a$ within the $k$ last chars?

Tags: automata

> Let be $k\ge1\in \mathbb{N}$. Is there a deterministic automata graph that recognizes the language $L_k=\{w|w \mbox{ contains an a within the k last chars}\}$ ?
>   The alphabet is $\{a,b\}$.

Reformulation : the question like is : How to construct an automata that does $L_k=\Sigma^*(\Sigma^k\mbox\ b^k)$. (I'm not sure, does it contains an a at the spcific position k or within the k last chars  ?).

I know how to do it for a specific $k$, but how to do it for any $k$ ?

#### My attempt from Brian Tung's idea

I created two states to begin with : a state where there has been at least $k$ characters since last $a$ and a state where there's been fewer than $k$ characters since last $a$ :

[image: attempt in graph]

I tried then to do it for $k=1$ and $k=2$.

[image]

But I don't know how to generalize...

Comment: You mean the *alphabet* is $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: I think a general schema of construction for any $k$ will do; is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes !

Comment: All right, I think J.-E.Pin has set me straight.  Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**General approach.** Have a set of states that keeps track of two quantities: (i) how many characters have been ingested in a row without an $a$, and (ii) how many characters are needed to reach at least $k$ characters for the string.  The initial state has (i) equal to $0$ and (ii) equal to $k$, and accepting states are those where (i) is less than $k$, and (ii) is equal to $0$.

Thus, for instance, for $k = 3$, the state $(1, 2)$ would indicate that the automaton has ingested one character without seeing an $a$, and that two more characters still have to be ingested to reach the minimum of $k = 3$ characters for the string.  This state could only be reached (for $k = 3$) after the string "$b$".

We move from state to state, either incrementing the number of characters seen without an $a$, or resetting it to zero; and decrementing the number of characters needed to reach a minimum of $k$.  Overall, for example, for $k = 3$, we have

[image]

All leftward transitions are $a$-transitions; all rightward transitions are $b$-transitions.

One final optimization can be obtained by observing that one may identify states $(k-1, 1)$ with $(k, 0)$ without affecting the automaton's behavior: Neither is an accepting state, and both go to $(0, 0)$ on an $a$ and to $(k, 0)$ on a $b$.  This saves one state and reduces the total state count from $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$ to $\frac{k(k+3)}{2}$.

---

**Previous, flawed approach.** Have a set of states that essentially counts how many characters it's been since the last $a$.  You don't need to count past $k$, so the number of states is finite.  If you end up in a state where there's been fewer than $k$ characters since the last $a$, you accept; if you end up in a state where there's been at least $k$ characters since the last $a$, you reject.

(ETA: This of course fails to count how many characters there are in the string.  Deepest thanks to J.-E.Pin for pointing this out in the comments.)

Comment: Than you for your answer. I updated my question with an attempt. Yet, I think my attempt isn't really smart even though it meets the constraints...

Comment: @Marine1: Your attempt won't work (hint: except for $k = 1$).  You need to have enough states to actually *count* the number of characters since the last $a$, not just say whether it's below $k$ or not.  For instance, suppose $k = 2$.  Then you need how many states?  Then suppose $k = 3$; in that case, you need how many states?

Comment: yes but I can't do a state for each of $k$ values ? [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkuKy.png)

Comment: @brian-tung How many states do you get for your DFA?

Comment: @Marine1: Why not?  I'm not sure I see a way to do it without something like that.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: $k+1$ (numbered most conveniently $0$ through $k$).  For instance, with $k = 2$, I need a state $0$ for when I've just started, or when I've just gotten an $a$, and I need a state $1$ when I've just gotten a $b$ after previously getting an $a$ (or just starting), and I need a state $2$ for when I've just gotten (at least) two $b$s in a row.

Comment: Then I am afraid your answer is plain wrong. The minimal DFA has $k(k+3)/2$ states.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Maybe I'm misinterpreting the language?  Otherwise, why doesn't a linear count work here?  I'm interpreting the language as containing those words with *at least* one $a$ in the last $k$ characters.  Did I miss a specification of *exactly* one $a$?  That would make the space $O(k^2)$, I could see that.

Comment: Just try by hand with the language $A^*(A^2 - bb)$, where $A = \{a,b\}$. The minimal DFA has 5 states.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: I will concede I must be missing something.  Let $Q = \{0, 1, 2\}, \Sigma = \{a, b\}, \delta(0, a) = 0, \delta(0, b) = 1, \delta(1, a) = 0, \delta(1, b) = 2, \delta(2, a) = 0, \delta(2, b) = 2, q_0 = 0, F = \{0, 1\}$.  What string in that language is not accepted, or what excluded string is accepted?

Comment: Only words of length $\geq 3$ should be accepted. For instance, the empty word and $a$ should not be accepted.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Ahh, of course, thanks.  I'll reconstruct.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Thanks, I couldn't do it without your assistance. :-)